# how to know port to device mapping of a hub in linux

Tags: linux, usb

I have a system where multiple USB ethernet devices (of same vendor) are connected to a USB hub. I have a physical mapping of which port has which ethernet interface. Is there a way I can identify the device programmatically to find the physical mapping to assign IP address etc.

Comment: is there any reason you can't just use the MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MAC address to identify the connected device. The first half of a MAC address identifies the manufacturer of the NIC (i.e 11:22:33 of 11:22:33:44:55:66 would identify the manufacturer).

Here is a website were you can enter a MAC address and get back the manufacturer: http://www.macvendorlookup.com/

One caveat is that the manufacturer of the NIC may not be the same as the manufacturer of the product in question. For example, I have a Dell laptop with a NIC manufactured by Intel.